# jQuery Append/Remove - appends, but no remove

Tags: jquery, append

```
   function addFormReqFields() { // Add * for required fields
        $('form label').each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
                $(this).append('<span class="required"> *</span>');
            }
        });
    }   

    $('#oh_CountryDrpDwn').change(function(){
        var CountryDrpDwn = $('#oh_CountryDrpDwn').val();
        if (CountryDrpDwn != 'usa')
        {
            $('#oh_ZipLbl').remove('<span class="required"> *</span>');
        }
        });
```

I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a form where all of the elements are initially set to required with a red asterisk. (first function).

In the second function, I have a select field (oh_CountryDrpDwn) that when the value is not equal to 'usa' I want to remove the `<span class="required"> *</span>` from the label.

But it doesn't seem to be triggering at all.

Any insight?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbARq/)

```
 $('#oh_ZipLbl').find('span.required').remove();
```

Remove takes a selector not HTML, if you change the content to span with class required, that might fix your problem.

Comment: I had that too, and unfortunately is not working. I'll post a fiddle shortly.

Comment: If you look at the Fiddle, its a working example of what you are trying to do. What do you have that I don't? Check your spelling, make sure you are referencing everything correctly.

Comment: Due to an odd conflict, the function wasn't triggering - just needed to add a document ready. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Jose Vega is exactly right, but I might add that you should consider using attach/detach, especially in this case, where you might need to reattach the element. It basically means, that the element is "removed", but not "destroyed", so you can reinsert it at will, without having to regenerate it.

```
$(".required").detach();
```

Read up on the difference between remove and detach here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1822-Learning-jQuery-1-4-Remove-vs-Detach-.htm

Comment: do you mean append/detach? I'm not sure there is an `attach` method.

Comment: Yes, yes, append(). Brain fart on my behalf. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

My initial thought is that the function needs to be told where to find the same element that you had initially appended to.

```
$(this).find('span.required').remove();
```

However, I am no expert, so there's no guarantee that this a good answer for you!